# non-ASCII file paths Windows

Tags: c++, windows, luajit, wstring

I work on Windows and have file paths with non-ASCII symbols. For non-ASCII symbols windows using wstring. I am doing the conversion and pass them to luaL_dofile but it fails with can not find a file.

Here is my example of code:

```
std::wstring wstr_path = "non-ASCII path"

using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>;
std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
std::string str_path = converter.to_bytes(wstr_path);
luaL_dofile(mRoot, str_path.c_str());
```

Comment: I checked the source. `luaL_dofile` calls `luaL_loadfilex`, which calls C `fopen`. For the Windows C runtime, `fopen` decodes the filename from the process active (ANSI) codepage and calls `CreateFileW`. The only way you'll get the full range of Unicode here is by setting the active process codepage to UTF-8 in the manifest of the executable, which is possible only in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about `luaL_dofile`, but it's rather unlikely it uses UTF-8. Windows file API for Unicode unaware programs uses the ANSI codepage (which corresponds to the system default locale). The ANSI codepage on English/US systems is 1252, but other system default locales have different codepages. Central European is 1250, Cyrillic is 1251, etc.

Also, you could try generating the short name for the file (see the `GetShortPathName` API) and feed that.